# How to avoid GroupMe bot from reading the same message twice when restarted on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, groupme

So essentially, my GroupMe bot will read in messages and look for specific commands.

Heroku automatically restarts my Dyno worker at least once every day.

However, when it does restart, my bot will scan over the last twenty messages and it will eventually find a command that it has already done, and then do the same thing again. Is there a way to fix this?

Code:

```
def main():

while True:
    response = requests.get(groupchat_url, params = request_params)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        response_messages = response.json()['response']['messages']
        for message in response_messages:
            if message['text'].startswith("/command"):
                <do something>
```

So, response_messages will have the past 20 messages and for each message, if it starts with "/command" then it will do something. When the bot restarts, it will do something again for the same command. I'm not sure if it's possible, but if someone knows something cool that could help solve this problem, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Do you care about messages received in the downtime during the restart? If not, just use a boolean `dry_run = True` above the loop and then later if set, it only fetches messages, but does not execute the command. At the end of the loop, set `dry_run = False`.

Comment: You'll have to provide a little info about how much data you're storing.  Every `message` has a `message.id` that comes with it.  (You'd access it as `message['id']` in your above code.)  You can change your request to request only messages since you're last message you processed with the `since_id` parameter.  Or you can make the request you already do, but store the message IDs for every command you process and compare new IDs against your processed list.

Comment: @DillonDavis I do care, but since the downtime isn't that long, it shouldn't be too bad? Don't know

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler Yeah I've tried since_id but since the bot restarts it will still read the command.
For storing message ID's, I would need some sort of database for that right?

Comment: @studentofcs A data storage mechanism of some sort, yeah. A database might be overkill for a small list of IDs, though.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler Thank you.